# How to make use of `keyof typeof myRecord` when myRecord is already typed as Record

Tags: typescript

Example 1:

```js
const myGroup = {
  Alice: { age: 5 },
  Bob: { age: 6 }, 
}
function getAge(name: keyof typeof myGroup) {
  return myGroup[name].age;
}
getAge('Charlie'); // error: name must be 'Alice' | 'Bob'
```

↑ This is what I want, however, if I type everything, it'll no longer work:

Example 2

```
interface People {
  age: number;
}

interface PeopleGroup {
  [name:string]: People;
}

const myGroup: PeopleGroup = {
  Alice: { age: 5 },
  Bob: { age: 6 }, 
}

function getAge(name: keyof typeof myGroup) {
  return myGroup[name].age;
}

getAge('Charlie'); // no error, name has type of string
```

I know I can solve it by using `enum` or `union type`, but that requires editing more than one place when adding people. In my real life project, `myGroup` is a big hard-coded dictionary with complicated structure, and I want to enjoy both typechecking when hard-coding it, and typechecking when querying it. Is there a dry way to do it?

Comment: Did you try using a Map instead of an object ? This data structure seems to fit your use case if I'm not mistaken. Map provide a `get` method to access a specific key/value pair, see [this](https://www.sharepointsky.com/typescript-map/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the issue is that when you say something is `Record<string, People>` then any string key is correct and type of `myGroup` is not narrowed to keys which are really there. In order to achieve type safe in two places:

- at the level of dictionary creating to have proper interface
- have narrowed type to exact keys of the dictionary

We need to introduce value constructor:

```
function makeGroup<T extends PeopleGroup>(input: T) {
  return input;
}
// using
const myGroup = makeGroup({
  Alice: { age: 5 },
  Bob: { age: 6 },
});
```

What it does is it takes something which match the interface `PeopleGroup` - its a first type safe element, it means that argument needs to be `PeopleGroup` and returns narrowed type. The second is very important, using generic type says TS that we want to infer exact type of the argument. In result as output we have exactly type of the argument.

Full code:

```
interface People {
  age: number;
}

interface PeopleGroup {
  [name:string]: People;
}

// value constructor
function makeGroup<T extends PeopleGroup>(input: T) {
  return input;
}

// correct creating of group - type safe for PeopleGroup
const myGroup = makeGroup({
  Alice: { age: 5 },
  Bob: { age: 6 },
});
const myGroupError = makeGroup({
  Alice: { age: 5 },
  Bob: { age: 'a' }, // error as it should be 
});

function getAge(name: keyof typeof myGroup) {
  return myGroup[name].age;
}

getAge('Alice') // ok !
getAge('Charlie'); // error as it should be
```

[The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=29&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoQPYAcA2KDeAUMsnAOYQBcyIArgLYBG0A3IQL6GGiSyIrpseAOJQMtLMiIkA2iDj0qAZzBRQZALrVBuCG06EA9IeQA3ODlooEGECqi0EYDFEIxaIJ8FvJ6cANYQouJYADwAKsgQAB6QIAAmSmiYusESAHwAFKBYtGDU4QCUUsTIUBBgtFAgyDl5%20lzGyDZQ5U7N5XBg6sgYMMhkYhLIALTIYACeWChKcDAoMC7JQkFDWIQ2dmC%20E2mSALy%20AashmdLIAII4wEjU%20KQU1ACsyOwANKUAQhiMdw9UyAAbK8PuxCmxNiodnsAKKtJaHPyBPZnUpXG4A%207kAEvd5fH5-bHUADkcGJIOQTWgYigpCSwG2SgAFuIcPFkMxkIBeDcAsjsccFcdyebo%20ChgC4UTLyRTUQITPrjKaYfr0XZrYrncqVarQtZyBQQDQAOmxDUIYolEEyxPRSGJxSaGH8yAAhOaKpbrQBhJlwKDXCD2liUkzUpZwemMlm0NkclC8oA)

Comment: But this way I lose the typechecking when hardcoding it

Comment: Ok sorry, now I think I know what you need, check the update

Comment: Hi Maciej, in practice I realized that due to how the "extend" keyword works, the typeguard won't guard against extra properties, for instance Alice {age: 5, height:4} won't show a warning when I hardcode it. Do you have any suggestions?